# How to test newly added stdlib module to ballerina parent project?

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to develop new stdlib to ballerina lang. (like stdlib/jms) It contains both ballerina functions and their native java implementations.

I need to test these ballerina functions. Is it possible to test them using a test case? If it is possible, could someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your are developing a new stdlib to ballerina-lang, what you are looking for is how to write an integration test. You can refer the [ballerina-lang](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang) github repo for a sample integration test case like [EchoServiceSampleTestCase](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/master/tests/ballerina-integration-test/src/test/java/org/ballerinalang/test/service/http/sample/EchoServiceSampleTestCase.java) which tests a part of the `stdlib/http` module.
Make sure that the new module you created has the correct `assembly` artifacts so that once the ballerina-lang repo is built, your new module gets added to the ballerina distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually I wanted to make some unit tests for the module. Anyway I figured it out by exploring the repo.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an integration test actually.. Just have a look at the ballerina-unit-test module. It contains the unit tests for Ballerina, including the units tests for the standard library.